# How to run sass

Tags: php, reactjs, sass, compiler-errors

I have following problem:
When I want to run sass I get error

```
Compilation Error
Error: File "c:\Users\Dell\Desktop\xxx\vendor\laravel\ui\src\Presets\bootstrap-stubs\~bootstrap\scss\bootstrap" not found
        on line 8 of sass/c:\Users\Dell\Desktop\eliadmin-new-design-backend\vendor\laravel\ui\src\Presets\bootstrap-stubs\app.scss
>> @import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';

   --------^

--------------------
Compilation Error
Error: File "c:\Users\Dell\Desktop\xxx\vendor\swagger-api\swagger-ui\src\style\~tachyons-sass\tachyons.scss" not found
        on line 3 of sass/c:\Users\Dell\Desktop\eliadmin-new-design-backend\vendor\swagger-api\swagger-ui\src\style\main.scss
>>     @import '~tachyons-sass/tachyons.scss';
```

I already used npm install and npm run dev. Any ideas what else I could do?